# Nasm add value from register to array

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm really new to assembly, especially NASM syntax, but I want to learn. My problem is that I didn't understand how to add values from a register, in my case edx, to an array.
I have a part of code that print the array that seems to work well:

```
print_array:
    mov ecx,32;move array length to ecx
    jmp iterate_array
iterate_array:
    mov eax,[result+ecx];move value from result+ecx into eax
    push    ecx;save ecx on stack
    push    eax;push & print eax
    push    formatin
    call    printf
    add esp,8       ;
    pop ecx
    dec ecx
    cmp ecx,0       ;
    jnz iterate_array
```

This part of code seems to work well. But the problem is when I'm trying to add a number in the array. I tried in the same manner:

```
xor ecx,ecx
jmp loop    
loop:
        xor edx,edx
        div ebx
        mov [result+ecx],edx
        inc ecx
        cmp eax,0       ;compare the quotient with 0;
        jnz loop
```

This 2 parts of code are from a simple program that should convert a decimal number to binary. The idea is that in loop I just divide eax to ebx and I want to store the remainder in the result array. 
But it seems that the method that I used doesn't work!

Results after running the program:
if I enter the number 2=> in loop eax is 2, in binary 0010 but the result is:
00000000000000000000000000000001
for number 3 =>in loop eax is 3, in binary 0011 but the result is:
00000000000000000000000000000001
for number 4=> in loop eax is 4, in binary 0100 but the result is:
0000000000000000000000000000001256

The problem is that I don't understand how to add the remainder from edx to array in loop. I thought that the method that I use in iterate_array, which seems to work ok ( display an array of 32 zeroes), should be enough.
Array was declared in .data section as:

```
section .data
result times 32 db  0
```

Comment: +1 only for `I'm really new to assembly, especially NASM syntax, but I want to learn.`

Comment: -1 for only saying "doesn't work" and not saying how it doesn't work. Nah, joking. But you should really have told us what the specific problem is. Also, use a debugger to step through the code. If I had to guess, your array is of integers so you should do `add ecx, 4` not `inc ecx`.

Comment: Ok, I'll update the question with some results after running the program!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strange output from your program stems from the fact that

```
mov eax,[result+ecx];move value from result+ecx into eax
```

reads garbage from the memory behind your RESULT buffer.

You say the program changes decimal to binary. So I think you use EBX=2 resulting in a remainder of 0 or 1
Change this line

```
mov ecx,32;move array length to ecx
```

to `mov ecx,31` and make use of byte registers where appropriate.

The answer you've provided yourself introduces a potential problem. Why do you ADD the remainder to the RESULT buffer in stead of using MOV ?

Comment: yes, I saw now that I add the remainder. Is just a mistake. I could use MOV. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is closed because I found a solution:

```
loop:
    xor edx,edx
    div ebx
    add dword[result+4*ecx],edx
    inc ecx
    cmp eax,0       ;compare the quotient with 0;
    jnz loop
print_array:
    mov ecx,size
    jmp iterate_array
iterate_array:
    mov eax,dword[result+4*ecx]
    push    ecx
    push    eax
    push    formatin
    call    printf
    add esp,8       ;
    pop ecx
    dec ecx
    cmp ecx,0       ;
    jge iterate_array
```